# Tell `ls` to print only the base filename

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, ls

This is the default behaviour of `ls`

```
ls /net/nas/data/languages/pypm/sites/rex/free/2.6/*/pool/v/vi/virtual*1.4.4*pypm
/net/nas/data/languages/pypm/sites/rex/free/2.6/linux-x86/pool/v/vi/virtualenv-1.4.4_linux-x86_2.6_1.pypm
/net/nas/data/languages/pypm/sites/rex/free/2.6/linux-x86_64/pool/v/vi/virtualenv-1.4.4_linux-x86_64_2.6_1.pypm
/net/nas/data/languages/pypm/sites/rex/free/2.6/macosx/pool/v/vi/virtualenv-1.4.4_macosx_2.6_1.pypm
/net/nas/data/languages/pypm/sites/rex/free/2.6/win32-x86/pool/v/vi/virtualenv-1.4.4_win32-x86_2.6_1.pypm
```

How do I make `ls` print only the basename? Like:

```
ls $OPTIONS /net/nas/data/languages/pypm/sites/rex/free/2.6/*/pool/v/vi/virtual*1.4.4*pypm
virtualenv-1.4.4_linux-x86_2.6_1.pypm
virtualenv-1.4.4_linux-x86_64_2.6_1.pypm
virtualenv-1.4.4_macosx_2.6_1.pypm
virtualenv-1.4.4_win32-x86_2.6_1.pypm
```

**Note**: I prefer shell globbing over using `find` as /net/nas/data/languages/pypm/sites/rex/free contains huge number of files and directories.

Comment: you prefer shell globbing OVER using find when the directory contains lots of files? typo??

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP doesn't want a listing of subdirectories, and is unaware of the option of passing `-maxdepth 1` to `find`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While `xargs -0` is intended to be used for input delimited by \0 (like `find -print0`), `ls` has no such option to delimit its output in this way.

However,

```
ls -1 /path/glob | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 1 basename
```

would do the trick to convert newlines to nulls along the way. This then allows xargs to work with names that have spaces.

EDIT: added `-n 1` to xargs

Comment: This does not work for me: `basename: extra operand `\033[0m/net/nas/data/languages/pypm/sites/rex/free/2.6/macosx/pool/v/vi/virtualenv-1.4.4_macosx_2.6_1.pypm\033[0m'`

Comment: @Sridhar: you might need the `-n 1` you suggested elsewhere as an option to `xargs` ? (answer edited)

Comment: Although I personally prefer my own answer (as I almost never have to deal with spaces in filenames), I will mark this as the answer for it handles spaces as well.

Comment: If the mac version of xargs supports the `-d` (delimiter) option, you can do `ls ... | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 basename`.

Comment: Would have thought just --- $ ls | xargs basename --- but found it problematic. This works.

Comment: Recall reading ls command is bad for xargs, and  find command is better.

Comment: Note comment below for answer below  - not sure why people keep upvoting this answer (ls | tr '\n' '\n' ) ... not only does it do the same thing as ls -1, it also does not work when globs have been used, as Daniel Beck pointed out. "

Comment: this works, but I wouldn't run this on a directory with hundreds or thousands of files. The awk/sed solutions are much more performant.

Answer (score 14):

I use this:

```
ls | tr '\n' '\n'
```

It gives a list like:

```
file1.mp3
file2.mp3
file3.mp3
...
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as `ls -1` (and coloring disabled), as `ls` implies those when not writing to a terminal. It looks like you're missing the point a bit, as the issue is stripping the dir name swhen specifying `ls` path arguments using wild cards. Try `ls -d "$PWD/"* | tr '\n' '\n'` to see what the actual issue is.

Comment: -1 – not sure why people keep upvoting this answer. Not only does it do the same thing as `ls -1`, it also does not work when globs have been used, as Daniel Beck pointed out.

Comment: -1 - This is the same as `ls -1`, and only works in the current directory, not with a path like `ls path/*`.

Answer (score 10):

Both [GNU basename](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/basename) and [FreeBSD basename](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=basename) accept an `-a` argument allowing you to pass multiple paths to the command. This works great with shell globbing.

```
basename -a /path/glob*
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ls -1 <path> | sed 's#.*/##'
```

Comment: AH! Finally something that works with multiple arguments!

Comment: much more performant than the accepted `basename` solution

Answer (score 4):

`awk` solution:

```
ls -1 /path/glob | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 2):

ls [optional path]| xargs -0 basename

Comment: -1: ls can't delimit names by \0 which is what `xargs -0` is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You said you prefer globbing over `find`, but did you know that the two are not mutually exclusive?  Globbing happens on any command you run, not just `ls`.  For example:

```
$ export BASE=/net/nas/data/languages/pypm/sites/rex/free/2.6

$ echo $BASE/*/pool/v/vi/virtual*1.4.4*pypm | xargs basename
$ ls $BASE/*/pool/v/vi/virtual*1.4.4*pypm | xargs basename
$ find $BASE/*/pool/v/vi/virtual*1.4.4*pypm -print0 | xargs -0 basename
```

Notice that the find example can make use of -print0 which handy if your paths contain whitespace (the `tr`-based solutions mentioned elsewhere work great on normal spaces, but not on files containing actual newlines).

Lastly, if you have access to GNU find, you can also use -printf which avoids the basename call altogether:

```
$ find $BASE/*/pool/v/vi/virtual*1.4.4*pypm -printf '%f\n'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `-printf` option is not available in MacOSX version of `find`.

Comment: Good call; apologies for the oversight.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

By using `cut` command:

```
ls -l |cut -d ' ' -f9
```

Comment: (1) Have you tried this?  (2) Try it with directories and wildcards on the command line, like in the question; e.g., ```ls vacation/*.jpg```.  (3) If you still think this is a good answer, try it with files with spaces in their names.